# Eval endpoint: set the modules database

Tags: marklogic

I am using the eval endpoint on 8000, on a specific content database: `/eval?database=xxx`

The query to evaluate imports a library from the modules database.  But I could not find any way to set it on the endpoint itself.

Did I miss how to set the modules database on `POST /eval`?

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct method of changing the modules DB via the standard REST interface (I presume you mean /v1/eval not /eval).
There are ways to do it that are a bit more challenging.   The app server on port 8000 uses the XML Rewriter in Modules/MarkLogic/rest-api/8000-rewriter.xml
This is not 'magic' -- it can be modified if you have system permissions (and if you take responsibility for what it might break).
There is a rewriter syntax to change the modules DB,  `<set-modules-database>`

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/XMLrewriter#id_67813

You can modify the rewriter.xml to key off a different path then /v1/eval , set the modules DB to a constant or parameter,  see the current implemenation for an example:
It is the section that starts with

```
<match-path matches="^/(v1|LATEST)/eval">
```

if you duplicate this with a different match-path (say /v1/myeval), being careful to pick one that is not used, you can add the  there.

Be warned, it does what its told to.  the modules database contains the code for the REST API itself so once the request leaves the rewriter it will no longer have access to ANY of the code in the default Modules DB.

Alternatives:

- create a new app server on a new port and do on that whatever you like.
- use xdmp:eval-in in your /v1/eval to run your query against a different modules DB.
  https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:eval-in
- Copy your server module code into the default Modules DB.
- Use the 'raw' xdbc /eval endpoint (not documented, it uses the same protocol as XCC/XDBC which you can inspect the public source code to infer how its done).
- Include the code of the intended-to-invoke module in with your code in the ad-hoc eval

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want in a couple of different ways using xdmp:eval in your query. Either *wrap the entire query in `xdmp:eval`*, or *use `xdmp:eval` on a small part of the query*.

#### Wrapping entire query in `xdmp:eval`

This is useful if you don't want to change the received query much by hand. However, it may require much more *escaping characters* so some automation may be necessary.

Given the following query

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace foo = "foo" at "foo.xqy";

let $bar := foo:fn()
let $_ := xdmp:log('some example logging with single quotes')
return $bar
```

Wrap as follows:

```
xdmp:eval('
  xquery version "1.0-ml";
  import module namespace foo = "foo" at "foo.xqy";

  let $bar := foo:fn()
  (: notice double-single-quotes below :)
  let $_ := xdmp:log(''some example logging with single quotes'') 
  return $bar 
  ', (), <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <modules>{xdmp:database("modules-db")}</modules>
  </options>
)
```

#### Using `xdmp:eval` in a small part

In most cases it will be simpler just to wrap that one part of the code you need in `xdmp:eval`. This requires escaping only a small part of the code and often none at all. However, it may involve passing variables from the query to the eval function as indicated in the following example.

Given the following query

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace foo = "foo" at "foo.xqy";

let $qux := 123
let $bar := foo:fn2($qux)
let $_ := xdmp:log('some example logging with single quotes')
return $bar
```

Convert as follows:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace ns="myns";

let $qux := 123
let $bar := xdmp:eval('
  declare namespace ns="myns";
  import module namespace foo = "foo" at "foo.xqy";
  foo:fn2($ns:qux)
  ', 
  ( xs:QName('ns:qux'), $qux),
  <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
    <modules>{xdmp:database("modules-db")}</modules>
  </options>
)
let $_ := xdmp:log('some example logging with single quotes')
return $bar
```